# Applying CSS to Drupal

Tags: html, css, drupal

I am working with drupal 8 and Ubercart. I am trying to change the color of the "Add to cart" button from red to green. Below is the code on each products page.

```
<input name="op" class="button js-form-submit form-submit" id="edit-submit-    32" type="submit" value="Buy Now" data-drupal-selector="edit-submit-32">
```

So what I did in my css file was the following...

```
#edit-submit-32
{
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #0F3;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

This obviously worked for this one particular product but I was wondering if there was some CSS I could use that would make this change for all my current products and all future products? The code for each products exactly the same only difference is the id tag for each product. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try using one of, if not more of the class attributes using the .selector rather than the #selector

Answer (score 2):

The first thing I would do is identify if all of these kinds of buttons have a similar parent container and then use that as a parent selector:

```
<div class="add-to-cart-wrapper">
  <input name="op" class="button js-form-submit form-submit" id="edit-submit-    32" type="submit" value="Buy Now" data-drupal-selector="edit-submit-32">
</div>

.add-to-cart-wrapper .button {  
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #0F3;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

Without more HTML context, I can't provide what the actual parent selector would be - *but for sake of example* I have added a div with the class "add-to-cart-wrapper". You would replace this selector with an applicable one.

It's also a good rule of thumb to try and use classes rather than IDs for your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

If you wouldn't mind changing all submit buttons, this would work:

```
.form-submit
{
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #0F3;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Or, if all of the buttons have value="Buy Now", then you could do this:

```
input[value="Buy Now"]
{
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #0F3;
    font-weight:bold;
}​
```

Comment: I wouldn't mind trying the second option out but I'm confused which selector to use the # or the . in that case ?

Comment: `#` is for the id of the element, which like you see in Drupal can be for a specific button that only appears on one page.

`.` is for classes of the element, which can appear on multiple elements, and in Drupal, is used on elements that are found on many pages.

I would try the `input[value="Buy Now"]` and see if that works.

Comment: So no selector then? I just tried that and its still red in the foreground but I can see some green in the back. Any reason why that would happen?

Comment: Yeah, the input[value...] is being overwritten by a class or id style. Do you use Firefox or Chrome? They let you inspect elements on the page to see what style declarations are being used, and which ones are being overwritten.

Comment: I've been using Edge, IE, and Chrome. I'm not near my computer right now (I'm on my phone right now) but when I get back to it, I assume I just right click on the button and then click inspect element? How would I find out which are being used and which are being overwritten?

Answer (score 0):

With Drupal (and CMS's in general) you need to look at the patterns that are generated by the theme to write your selectors. Whenever possible (and with Drupal's default themes it's nearly always possible) you want to avoid IDs and use classes. The classes are intended to be used to target multiple elements and help you write reusable elements.

It's worth taking a little time reviewing the generated HTML in some detail to get your head around what's being generated. You may also want to review some of the [basic themeing guides](https://www.drupal.org/theme-guide/8) so you can understand how you can take control of the generated markup.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @acrosman I will keep that in mind. I will say that I did really like the idea of using Dave concept of using:   input[value="Buy Now"]
{
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #0F3;
    font-weight:bold;
}​ but I cant figure out why the green is still being overwritten by the red.